# Kali Linux boots from USB, black screen after boot option

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, kali-linux

Trying to figure out what's going on with my laptop. As you can see in the picture below, Kali Linux boots, but upon selecting live system boot or "start installer" I'm presented with a black box in the foreground. I booted the Kali Linux USB from my desktop and it worked just fine. My graphics drivers are up to date on the laptop. Spent about two hours trying to figure this out for my class work. Any help greatly appreciated, thank you.

Obeyed Kali Linux USB ISO, obeyed dual boot installation. Issue arises at Dual boot launch.

Bios options attempted:

- Safeboot On/Off,
- Virtual hardware On/Off,
- Graphics mode Switchable/Discrete

Machine specs:

- Lenovo Yoga 720,
- Windows 10 64bit,
- 16gb RAM,
- i7-7700HQ
- nvidia 1050

[image: Black screen image 1]

[image: Black screen image 2, note there is no information given on the black screen]

Answer (score -1):

The problem was I did not enable legacy boot. After I enabled legacy boot everything is fine.